# Generating template with some logic via HStringTemplate

Tags: templates, haskell, hstringtemplate

Here is some invalid [`HStringTemplate`](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/HStringTemplate) syntax:

```
option_a = $options.a$
option_b = $options.b$
$if options.option_c_is_needed$
option_c = $option.c$
$end$
```

In other words, part of template file should be created only if specific predicate is true. How can it be achieved via [`HStringTemplate`](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/HStringTemplate)? If there is no way to do that in it, what libraries could be helpful here?

May be there is some analog of [`erubis`](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/users-guide.html) mechanism with ability to use `haskell` code inside template files?

Comment: Assuming [the syntax matches the Java version](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST/Five+minute+Introduction), I _think_ that should be `$if(expr)$ ... $endif$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hammar's comment is correct. See below:

```
*Main Text.StringTemplate> render $ setAttribute "optSet" False $ (newSTMP "OptSet: $if(optSet)$Option Is Set$else$Option Isn't Set$endif$" :: StringTemplate String)
"OptSet: Option Isn't Set"
*Main Text.StringTemplate> render $ setAttribute "optSet" True  $ (newSTMP "OptSet: $if(optSet)$Option Is Set$else$Option Isn't Set$endif$" :: StringTemplate String)
"OptSet: Option Is Set"
```